# How to run application of the first with click on the button in android?

Tags: android, onclick

I'm writing a android game. I want to click on button, all application runs of the first.

This is my code:

```
newgame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

This works but when user onBackPressed, opens previous page instead of application is closed. How can i do that run my app again of the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the `Activity` like this:

```
public void restartActivity() {
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

And call the above method from the `onClick` event:

```
newgame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            restartActivity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. worked but previous game continues because I used of sound for winning or losing and with new start, previous game voice is heard.

Comment: @Digipng, I am not sure how are you playing that sound and thus can't say anything about it. Why don't you post it as a different question. :)

Comment: @Rohit Arya, With restartActivity(), all program must be run of the first, not that along with the current game the previous game continues.

Comment: @Digipng, You would have to show some code. I can't get how are you playing the game/sound. Can you put that in some other question?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

/* destroy any life cycle of any sound, and voice here or 
anything need to be disposed */

    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

Good Luck...